# Jquery Ajax call to Rest service error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, rest

I have made a Rest Web Service:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/todo")
public class TodoResource {
  @GET
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  public Todo getXML() {
    Todo todo = new Todo();
    todo.setSummary("This is my first todo");
    todo.setDescription("This is my first todo");
    return todo;
  }
  @GET
  @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_XML })
  public Todo getHTML() {
    Todo todo = new Todo();
    todo.setSummary("This is my first todo");
    todo.setDescription("This is my first todo");
    return todo;
  }
}
```

When I go to internet explorer & type this in the address bar:

```
http://localhost:8080/LondonAirQuality.Rest/rest/todo/
```

It is giving me:

```
{"description":"This is my first todo","summary":"This is my first todo"}
```

But when I call it using an ajax call in a JQuery method. e.g.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:8080/LondonAirQuality.Rest/rest/todo/",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) { 
    alert('OK : ' + data);
  },    
  error: function (e) {
    alert('KO: '+ e.text);
    console.log(e);
    alert("Status is: " + e.statusText);
  }
});
```

I am getting an Error in this call, but in Firebug I see request is 200 OK and in the response the correct json.
[image]
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Are you sure request in Firebugbelongs to call from jQuery but not the one you did from URL? Can you try using `done()` and `fail()` instead of `error` and `success`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure of this. I do the calls in different tab. If I use done and fail instead of error and success, the output doesn't pass through any of them

Comment: Did you try done and fail?

Comment: If I use done and fail instead of error and success, the output doesn't pass through any of them

Comment: The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the "same origin policy" and the solution have been to add the class ResponseCorsFilter to the server:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

public class ResponseCorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest req, ContainerResponse contResp) {

    ResponseBuilder resp = Response.fromResponse(contResp.getResponse());
    resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");

    String reqHead = req.getHeaderValue("Access-Control-Request-Headers");

    if(null != reqHead && !reqHead.equals("")){
        resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", reqHead);
    }

    contResp.setResponse(resp.build());
        return contResp;
}

}
```

And add an init-param to Jersey Servlet:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>de.vogella.jersey.jaxb.security.ResponseCorsFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Thanks. I hope this can help someone.